# Best practice to apply bitwise AND logic on SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to find the best way to apply the following logic. Our business logic requires me to insert a bunch of rows into a var table, then select all distinct records but set a condition to positive only if it matches all records with same id [So basically bitwise AND]

Hopefully my example explains that better.

```
DECLARE @sometable TABLE (
record_id INT NOT NULL,
some_condition BIT NOT NULL)
```

records in that table would match

```
record_id some_condition
1         1
1         0
2         0
3         0
```

In the above case the desired output should be

```
record_id some_condition
1         0
2         0
3         0
```

Till now how I've been doing this is like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT record_id  CAST(MIN(CAST(some_condition INT)) AS some_condition
FROM @sometable
GROUP BY record_id
```

Is there a better way to do this? I'm having to CAST the var as MIN only takes numeric types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can leave out `DISTINCT`, since `GROUP BY` already makes them distinct.  Also, you can avoid the innermost `CAST` if you just add 0:

```
SELECT record_id,  CAST(MIN(some_condition+0) as BIT) AS some_condition
FROM @sometable
GROUP BY record_id
```

Finally, do you really need to recast to a BIT when done?  Depending on how the query results are used, that might not be needed.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I do, our DAL Layer code expects a BIT, but I like the trick with a +0

Comment: @BarendB Your Data Acess Layer Layer? ;)

Comment: LOL Typo... Yeah it's a layer withing a layer :P

Comment: Reminds me of that old software adage. "Software is like an onion. The more tiers, the more tears". :o)

Answer (score 1):

how about using a case statement?

```
select record_id,
min(case when some_condition=0 then 0 else 1 end) as minCond
from sometable
group by 
record_id
```

Comment: Huh ? On sql-server-2008, is not "true" = 1 ? If so, your case becomes "when cond=false then false else true" *(the "min" of which only makes sense should "true" ever be something like -1)*

Comment: Black Light, he's identified his values for some_condition in his post, that's the data I was using.